# Since applying localisation middleware query params now never pass through in the url NextJs 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, localization, middleware, next.js13

I have written and applied localisation middleware to my NextJS13 app so there are two locales for the site for translations. However I have since discovered that now query params no longer pass through the url which are being passed through in a Next Link component.

I can see in my middleware when I console log the request that the search params are in the request url. But when re-written we lose the search params all together.

How do I have the url rewritten so that it keeps its search params?

middleware code is below:

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextMiddleware, NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { match } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher";
import Negotiator from "negotiator";
import { request } from "http";
import { i18n } from "@/i18n.config";

let defaultLocale = "en-US";

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales;
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();

  const locale = match(languages, locales, defaultLocale);

  return locale;
}

export default function localisationMiddleware(middleware: NextMiddleware) {
  return async (request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) => {
    // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

    // console.log("Request url", request.url);
    const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
      locale => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
    );

    // Redirect if there is no locale
    if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
      console.log("NO LOCALE REDIRECRING");
      const locale = getLocale(request);

      console.log("REQUEST", request);


      // e.g. incoming request is /products
      // The new URL is now /en-US/products
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        new URL(`/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}`, request.url)
      );
    }

    return middleware(request, event);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, here is the solution:

First, catch your params in the middleware, like that:

```
  const {
    nextUrl: { search },
  } = req;
  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

  const urlParams = '?' + new URLSearchParams(params);
```

With that, just pass your urlParams in the redirect, like that:

```
 return NextResponse.redirect(
    new URL(`/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}${urlParams}`, request.url)
  );
```